QGIS How to Transformation ITRF2020(EPSG:9989) Dynamic(Current Epoch) to Nad83(csrs)v7(EPSG:22717) Fixed
Background:
QGIS version Maidenhead 3.36.3
QField version Congo 3.2.2
I have a QGIS project with a project CRS EPSG:22717.
I have 2 GPKG layers.
The first has an assigned CRS EPSG:9989
The second has an assigned CRS EPSG:22717
I load the project into QField using QFieldCloud
I use the first layer when using correction data provided by PointPerfect(ITRF2020 quarterly eg:2024.090) Epoch with my U-Blox C099-F9P rover when I'm too far from a ntrip base station.
The second layer is used when I connect to my ntrip base station on RTK2GO. The base is referenced to NAD83(csrs)v7 provided by Natural Resources PPP.
Issue:
I observe the same control point using each layer with the appropriate correction data. I want to be able to transform each layer to the other layer if needed.
I used GDAL:ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" -s_srs EPSG:9989 -s_coord_epoch 2024.090 -t_srs EPSG:22717 -t_coord_epoch 2010.001
The coordinates used to move to the correct location when using the previous version of QGIS? but now this doesn't happen.
Coordinates from Layer 1
Lat: 43.918799362083334
Log: -80.09282164175
Elipsoid Elev:(h)387.746
Coordinates from Layer 2
Lat:43.918789904083326
Long:-80.09281167791666
Elipsoid Elev:(h)388.852
I can use Natural Resources Canada "TRX" software to transform the layer 1 coordinates and it works.
I assume that QField transforms Layer 1 to EPSG:22717 when storing a point. I store the Lat, Long, h of the sensor into fields in the layer.
Has anyone have any insights into how to solve this?
